# Ошибка 404 при запросе с клиента

Tags: node.js

Возникает ошибка 404 при пост запросе на сервер с клиента[image: Ошибка]

При запросе через программу postman всё отлично работает.
Код сервера:

```js
app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log('klsafjdaksldfj')
  return res.json({mes: "USSS"})
})
```

Клиент и сервер на одном порту.

Comment: а можно скриншоты с postman'a?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8z5yESR